# Horizontal scrolling for a HTML list

Tags: html, css

I want to make my list horizontally scrollable, but whatever I do, it seems to just wrap the content by width. My list is inside of a table cell.

HTML:

```
<td class="scrollable"> 
  <ol>
    <li> bla bla bla bla </li>
  </ol>
</td>
```

CSS:

```
td {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: auto;
}


ol {
  height: 160px;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;

  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

li {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  width: 95%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline;
}

.scrollable {
  width: 10%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

How can I make it horizontally scrollable?

Answer (score 2):

The scrollbar will appear only when there is a need for it. You simply don't have enough content to make it scroll. Feel free to ask if you are facing any other issue.

**Try below HTML :**

```
<td class="scrollable">
  <ol>
    <li> bla bla bla bla  bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla blabla bla bla bla</li>
  </ol>
</td>
```

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nikdtu/d7u2c1b7/

Answer (score 0):

If you want only your list to be scrollable inside table cell, not all page, then you must set some width to this list, try add more content and set `ol` width to 100px.